# React app is stuck at loading at loading and doesn't render the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-18

I am unable to render header component in the App component. Not sure if something has changed in react 18, it just keeps on loading on the local host. Please find the code snippet below. Could someone please help?

Header.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

function Header() {
  return (
    <Header className='container'>
        <h2>React App</h2>
    </Header>  
  )
}

export default Header
```

App.js

```
import Header from "./components/Header"
function App() {
    return (
        <>
          <Header/>
        </>
    )
}
export default App
```

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import './index.css'
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: The header component is most likely causing an infinite loop since it's rendering itself repeatedly.

Comment: Yes seems so, is there any different way to render, I just want to render it into main app component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seens you are not using ang ui-kit that includes a component name `<Header/>` then ,i guess your root tag : `<Header></Header>` in **Header.jsx** is wrong, do you mean `<header></header>` ?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I am sorry for the silly mistake.  Thank you for spotting.